# fileupload() in php not working with session

Tags: php, session, file-upload

I am trying to upload a pdf file using `fileupload()` function in php. This works great when no session is used but gives an error with session.

This is how I defined a session:

```
 session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['name']))
{
$name=$_SESSION['name'];
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
```

and here is the fileupload() function:

```
function fileupload()
{
$corname = $_POST['corname'];
 define ("FILEREPOSITORY","./upload");

$filename = './upload/'.$corname.'.pdf';
//echo $filename;

   if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])) 
   {

      if ($_FILES['file']['type'] != "application/pdf") 
      {
         echo "<p>Class notes must be uploaded in PDF format.</p>";
      } 


     else if(file_exists($filename))
        {
      echo "already exist";
       }

        else 
      {
         //$name = $_POST['corname'];
         $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], FILEREPOSITORY."/$corname.pdf");
         if ($result == 1) 
            {echo "<p>File successfully uploaded.</p>";
            $cata=$_POST['cata'];
$subcata=$_POST['subcata'];
$corname = $_POST['corname'];
$heading=$_POST['headng'];
$descrip=$_POST['descrip'];
$cno=$_POST['cno'];
$credit=$_POST['credit'];
$fee=$_POST['fee'];
            $qry="insert into course (catagory,subcatagory,courseno,coursename,heading,description,credit,fee,coursefilename) values ('$cata','$subcata','$cno','$corname','$heading','$descrip','$credit','$fee','$corname')";
$ins_qry=mysql_query($qry);
if($ins_qry)
{
echo "Successfully Inserted<br>";
}
else
{
echo mysql_error();
}}
         else {echo "<p>There was a problem uploading the file.</p>";}
       } #endIF
   } #endIF

}}
```

This is the error message I get:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function fileupload() in
>   C:\wamp\www...\course_submit_process.php on
>   line 66

I have checked everything for some error but can't reach for any solution. Please let me know if I am missing something.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with a session? I think that confuses the matter a bit: the error is `undefined function fileupload`, that's a hint :)

Comment: $name=$_SESSION['name'];
$_SESSION['name']=$name; doesnt make much sense?

Comment: yes, it is `undefined function error not session`

Comment: where you put fileupload()? if it is not in course_submit_process.php, have you include the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't include the file that has the `fileupload()` method in it.

So on top of `course_submit_process.php`:

```
include "file_containing_fileupload()";
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code posted you don't end the first IF condition with }. That might cause your problem if the fileupload() function follows.

An 'undefined' function has nothing to to whether you initiated PHP sessions or not. So look into the error message instead. 'Undefined' error happens when the function is unknown at the point when the function is first called.